# Orthonormal basis quadratic form in canonical form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, orthonormal

I am very confused and don't know what to do, can you give me any suggestions?
This is my task:

In orthonormal basis quadratic form F(x) is calculated like this:
$$F(x) = 17x^2
_1 + 17x^2_2 + 11x
^2_3 − 16x_1x_2 + 8x_1x_3 − 8x_2x_3.$$
Find transformation matrix to another orthonormal basis, in which $F$ is in canonical form, and find this canonical form.

Comment: Do you mean "canonical form of quadratic form" = only $\;\pm1,\,0\;$ on the main diagonal, or "canonical form" = diagonal form with eigenvalues on the main diagonal? Many times the first want is what is meant with quadratic forms, e.g. in Sylverster's Law of Inertia, yet sometimes it is enough with the "usual* diagonalization. Both cases are nasty this times, though...In fact, it seems it is unusually nasty! Are you sure that is the quadratic form you were given?

Comment: i mean  "canonical form of quadratic form"

Comment: I started calculating the canonical form of the quadratic form but there were very nasty numbers so i tought i was doing something wrong- may be there is something i don't see

Comment: @Ed Nop, it really looks nasty in a rather extreme way. Even the usually nice Lagrange's Method of completing the square seems to be nasty here , since it would begin as $$17\left(x-\frac8{18}x_2+\frac4{17}x\right)^2+\ldots$$ When something begins as above I usually retire. Good luck, most probably you are in the right track...

Comment: @DonAntonio The form with $\pm1,0$ on the diagonal can’t be achieved with the required transformation.

Comment: @amd I'd love to know how, without Lagrange or elementary row/column congruence on the form's matrix or without the eigenvalues (and not sure the OP wants this last one) , could you get that...True, one can with only the eigenvalues know the signature, number of positive/negative/zero eigenvalues and thus or $\;\pm1, 0\,'$ s, but there's quite a lot of work.

Comment: @DonAntonio The original formula is expressed relative to an orthonormal basis. The question asks for a transformation to another orthonormal basis, so you’re limited to orthogonal transformations. These preserve the determinant of the quadratic form’s matrix, which is neither $\pm1$ nor $0$.

Comment: @amd The OP's wrote he wants "Canonical form for quadratic forms. This could well mean the matrix decomposed (by congruence) with $\;\pm 1\,'$ ones or zeros on the main diagonal. True, orthogonal operators (application) don't change determinants...and still it doesn't look easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quadratic form is represented by a unique symmetric matrix $S$ in the sense that $F(x)=x\cdot Sx$. In this case, the matrix $S$ is
$$
S=\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
17 & -8 & 4 \\
-8 & 17 & -4 \\
4 & -4 & 11
\end{array}\right]
$$
To construct this $S$, note that the $(i, j)$th entry is half the coefficient of $x_ix_j$ in $F(x)$ if $i\neq j$ and equal to the coefficient of $x_ix_j$ if $i=j$.

The process of putting $F$ in "canonical form" is sometimes referred to as "completing the square." The strategy here is to diagonalize $S$ as $S=QDQ^\top$ where $Q$ is *orthogonal* ($Q^\top=Q^{-1}$). We then "change variables" by defining $y=Q^\top x$. Our quadratic form can then be written as
$$
F(x)
= x\cdot Sx
= x^\top QDQ^\top x
= (Q^\top x)^\top D (Q^\top x)
= y^\top D y
= \lambda_1\cdot y_1^2 + \lambda_2\cdot y_2^2 + \lambda_3\cdot y_3^2
$$
where the $\lambda_i$'s are the diagonal entries of $D$ (which are also the eigenvalues of $S$).

To go about this process, we need to find *orthonormal bases* for the eigenspaces of $S$. It's not terribly difficult to show that this $S$ has two eigenvalues $\lambda_1=27$ and $\lambda_2=9$. Bases for the eigenspaces are given by
\begin{align*}
E_{27} &= \operatorname{Null}(S-27\cdot I_3)=\operatorname{Span}\{\left\langle2,\,-2,\,1\right\rangle\} \\
E_{9} &= \operatorname{Null}(S-9\cdot I_3) = \operatorname{Span}\{\left\langle1,\,0,\,-2\right\rangle, \left\langle0,\,1,\,2\right\rangle\}
\end{align*}
Note, however, that these bases are not *orthonormal*. To make them orthonormal, we can apply the [Gram-Schmidt algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process). Can you carry out this algorithm and finish "completing the square"?

Comment: We only need GS method for the basis of $\;E_9\;$ , as eigenvectors corresponding to different eigenvalues are already orthogonal. Still, there's the work to find out the eigenvalues. Not so nice with this matrix, though...

Comment: @DonAntonio It’s not quite as bad as it seems at first, I think. One eigenvector/eigenvalue pair can be found by inspection, which lets you reduce computing the eigenvalues to solving a quadratic equation.

Comment: @amd I thought I have quite some experience with these but perhaps not as much as I thought: I can't see anything by inspection that you say. I already know what the eigenvalues are since I began working on this question for a little while until I got annoyed by the quantity of work required. Anyway, why won't you write down your own answer? Maybe there are some insights we all can learn from.

Comment: @DonAntonio The eigenvector doesn’t instantly jump out at me like it does in other exercises, but having $4$ and $-4$ at the bottom of the first two columns suggested trying $(1,1,0)^T$.

Comment: @DonAntonio I like to remind my students that Gram-Schmidt in dimension one is the same as normalization. So applying Gram-Schmidt to $E_{27}$ is the same as normalizing the given non-unit basis vector.